# Why panic with already brrowed error on using if let?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm using Rc<RefCell> to update data. But in the following example, the previous usage will cause a runtime error, and the second usage is okay.

My question is :

1. What is the difference between the two usages?
2. Why is the first one causing a runtime error? Does it borrow anything?

```
fn main() {
    struct Test;
    impl Test{
        fn foo(&self) -> Option<u32>{
            Some(0)
        }
        fn bar(&mut self){
            println!("bar")
        }
    }

    let x = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Test{}));

    // Runtime panic: already borrowed!
    if let Some(foo) = x.borrow().foo(){
        x.borrow_mut().bar();
    }

    // Run perfectly!
    let foo = x.borrow().foo();
    if let Some(foo) = foo{
        x.borrow_mut().bar();
    }

    ()
}
```

Comment: Because the lifetime of a temporary [is extended to the whole statement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes), in the first case that's the whole `if`.

Comment: @cafce25 Sorry, I don't understand, do you mean that the borrow occurs in the whole if block?

Comment: In case 2 the borrowed value is dropped after the assignment `foo = ...;`  is finished.